# Node.js | TypeError: [...] is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

In my main file server.js I have following function:

**server.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const SmallRounds = require('./models/smallrounds.js');

function initRound(){
    logger.info('Initializing round...');
    SmallRounds.getLatestRound((err, data) => {
        [...]
    });
}
```

the function getLatestRound() gets exported in my mongoose model smallrounds.js

**smallrounds.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('../config.js');

const SmallRoundsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    [...]
});

const SmallRounds = module.exports = mongoose.model('SmallRounds', SmallRoundsSchema);

module.exports.getLatestRound = function(callback){
    SmallRounds.findOne().sort({ created_at: -1 }).exec((err, data) => {
        if(err) {
            callback(new Error('Error querying SmallRounds'));
            return;
        }
        callback(null, data)
    });
}
```

But when I call initRound() I get following error:

> TypeError: SmallRounds.getLatestRound is not a function
>
> at initRound (E:\Projects\CSGOOrb\server.js:393:14)
>   at Server.server.listen (E:\Projects\CSGOOrb\server.js:372:2)
>   at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:314:30)
>   at emitNone (events.js:110:20)
>   at Server.emit (events.js:207:7)
>   at emitListeningNT (net.js:1346:10)
>   at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:11)
>   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
>   at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:607:11)
>   at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
>   at bootstrap_node.js:575:3

Why is this happening? I don't think that I have circular dependencies and have not misspelled anything. Thanks :)

Comment: Maybe the object returned in `mongoose.model` is frozen or something? Make sure the file you are requiring is exactly as it is in this post.

Comment: It is, I copy pasted the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how you add methods to Mongoose models/schemas.

Try this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('../config.js');

const SmallRoundsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    [...]
});

SmallRoundsSchema.statics.getLatestRound = function(callback){
    this.findOne().sort({ created_at: -1 }).exec((err, data) => {
        if(err) {
            callback(new Error('Error querying SmallRounds'));
            return;
        }
        callback(null, data)
    });
}

const SmallRounds = module.exports = mongoose.model('SmallRounds', SmallRoundsSchema);
```

You can read the documentation here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html, in the section "Statics". There are other, better ways of achieving the same result, but this will get you started.

Comment: Huge thank you. I really don't know what happened with my code, I've been using module.exports for these functions for months and never had problems, except for today where it suddenly stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

I was using upper-case module, and getting error `TypeError: upperCase is not a function`
l

```
et upperCase =require("upper-case") ;
res.end(upperCase("Hello World"));
```

as every tutorial written in this way.

I changed it to

```
res.end(upperCase.upperCase("Hello World"));
```

and working fine